# R Studio is adding my data together when stacking?

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart comparing the seats won by Cons and Labour in an election (fun, I know.) I'm a beginner to R Studio and have this so far, which would be perfect, except....

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

elections <- data.frame(Country = c("England", "NI", "Scotland", "Wales"), 
Con = c(291, 0, 13, 8), Lab = c(200, 0, 7, 28))

elections_long <- melt(elections, id = "Country")

ggplot(elections_long, aes(x = Country, y = value)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill = variable)) +
ggtitle("Seats Won By Labour and Conservative In the United Kingdom") +
labs(y= "Amount of Seats Won", x = "Country") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#53a0ed", "#f71d1d")) +
labs(fill = "Party")
```

It produces this -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZORA.png

It's pretty close to what I want, but R Studio is instead adding any value I have for Labour and making it apart of Conservatives bar.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing in my code that is making this happen? Or is there something I can write in to stop the Conservative data from absorbing the Labour data?

Also - if anyone knows a way to flip that last bar so that Conservative is "in front" of Labour (Labour gained more seats in my data - but instead Conservative is sitting on top of Labour and is taller - ideally I want the blue bar to be small, and the red bar to rise up "behind" it)

Thank you!

Update - If I change the number for the first lot of data to "91" for Conserv. it plots it where I want it (at 291)  - Don't know if this is a common thing or what but maybe that info helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behaviour for `geom_bar` is to stack the groups on top of each other (see [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)) but it sounds like you don't want a stacked bar chart - it only looks like a value for Labour is part of the Conservatives bar because the bars are stacked on top of each other.  It's the relative height of the bars that counts in a stacked bar chart (not the absolute height).

If you use `position=position_dodge()` then the different parties are plotted beside each other.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

elections <- data.frame(Country = c("England", "NI", "Scotland", "Wales"), 
Con = c(291, 0, 13, 8), Lab = c(200, 0, 7, 28))

elections_long <- melt(elections, id = "Country")
names(elections_long) <- c("Country", "Party", "Votes")

ggplot(elections_long, aes(x = Country, y = Votes, fill = Party)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) + 
ggtitle("Seats Won By Labour and Conservative In the United Kingdom") +
labs(y= "Amount of Seats Won", x = "Country") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#53a0ed", "#f71d1d")) +
labs(fill = "Party")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify the bit about it being a relative height? I'm confused because I've told the blue bar to be 291, and the labour one to be 200, but instead it's made the blue bar 491? Is there a way around this that still means the bars stay stacked?

Comment: The point of them being "stacked" is that they stack on top of each other.  That's the definition of a "stacked barchart".  In your original code you told the blue bar to be a height of 291 and the labour one to be a height of 200 (which is different from asking the blue bar to go from 0 to 291).  Going from 200 to 491 still means that the bar has a height of 291.

Comment: Both plots are correct, it just depends on how you want to display the data.

Comment: ahhhhh thank you! I'm not mathmatically minded at all (could you tell?) you've been a big help!